# MVC 4 Model binding with partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, binding, partial-views

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PrintDoorSigns", "TimeTable", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "printDoorSigns" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" id="doorSignDate" name="SelectedDate" />
    <h3>Door Signs</h3>
    <fieldset class="float-left">
        <legend>Date</legend>
        <div id="signsDate"></div>
    </fieldset>
    <div id="doorSignsRoomList" class="float-left">
        @{Html.RenderAction("DoorSignsForm", new { date = DateTime.Now });}
    </div>
    <div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Options</legend>
        <button id="SelectAllRooms">Select All</button>
        <button id="RemoveAllRooms">Remove All</button>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

I have this form which renders this partial view:

```
@model WebUI.ViewModels.CalendarVM.DoorSignsFormVM

<fieldset>
    <legend>Rooms</legend>
    @{ var htmlListInfo = new HtmlListInfo(HtmlTag.vertical_columns, 3, null, TextLayout.Default, TemplateIsUsed.No);
        if (Model.Rooms.Count() > 0)
        {
            <div id="roomsWithBookings" class="CheckBoxList float-left">
                @Html.CheckBoxList("SelectedRooms", model => model.Rooms, entity => entity.Value, entity => entity.Text, model => model.SelectedRooms, htmlListInfo)
            </div>
        }
    }   
</fieldset>
```

Controller action:

```
public ActionResult PrintDoorSigns(DateTime SelectedDate, DoorSignsFormVM Model)
```

when I submit the form, the hidden input "SelectedDate" gets passed back fine and the Model variable which contains two IEnumerable variables isn't null. One of the lists is null which I expect, as it shouldn't be passed back and the SelectedRooms variable which I expect to be populated is a new list with count 0.

I assume the binding is just wrong on this property but I don't understand why, any pointers? Thanks

EDIT:

```
    public PartialViewResult DoorSignsForm(DateTime date)
    {
        var userID = _bookingService.GetCurrentUser(User.Identity.Name);

        var model = new DoorSignsFormVM();
        model.Rooms = _sharedService.GetRoomsWithBookings(date, userID.FirstOrDefault().DefSite);

        return PartialView("_DoorSigns", model);
    }
```

Here is the doorsignsform action that gets rendered in the form.

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing a DoorSignsFormVM model to the RenderAction method here Html.RenderAction("DoorSignsForm", new { date = DateTime.Now })? Could you post the code for the DoorSignsForm action?

Comment: Added it to the main question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, ASP.NET MVC is not recognizing the checkbox values as being part of the `DoorSignsFormVM` view model.

Given that your `SelectedRooms` property is a collection of `SelectListItem`s, MVC is not recognizing how to bind the string values from the checkboxes to this property.

Try adding another property called SelectedRoomValues of type string[] to your viewmodel and change your checkbox code to

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.SelectedRoomValues, model => model.Rooms, entity => entity.Value, entity => entity.Text, model => model.SelectedRooms, htmlListInfo)
```

MVC will then know how to bind to this new property, which will be populated with the `SelectListItem.Value` values.

Comment: I tried this however all it did when I changed it to "DoorSignsFormVM.SelectedRooms" was make the object in the controller action have two null lists instead of one null and a one with a count of 0. You can't use a lambda for the first argument either sadly, as it complains that it expects a string :(

Comment: Did you try using the overload of @Html.CheckBoxList that takes a lambda, rather than a string?

Comment: You could also change the `SelectedRooms` property on your viewmodel from a collection of `Room` objects to be a string array and see if that works.

Comment: All 16 overloads expect a string for the listName as the first argument

Comment: Sorry, the lambda is available in `@Html.CheckBoxListFor` rather than `@Html.CheckBoxList`

Comment: No worries, just given that a go and it's the same as before, the list contains no elements. It may also be worth a mention that I have a jQuery datepicker on the form and when a different date is clicked, the partial view is reloaded to display a different list of rooms. So maybe this has an effect?

Comment: It could be having an effect. Try changing the `SelectedRooms` property on your viewmodel from a collection of `Room` objects to be a string array (`string[]`) which will store the Room.Value values.

Comment: Currently the `SelectedRooms` property on the viewmodel is a collection of SelectListItems, I wouldn't be able to change this to an array of strings because CheckBoxListFor expects SelectListItem :/

Comment: Try adding another property called `SelectedRoomValues` of type `string[]` and change your checkbox code to `@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.SelectedRoomValues, model => model.Rooms, entity => entity.Value, entity => entity.Text, model => model.SelectedRooms, htmlListInfo)`

Comment: That posted values to the controller action!

Comment: Great, I have updated the answer to reflect this. Would you be able to accept it if it has helped you?